# How to pick correct method overload for function composition?

Tags: f#

Here is a simple composition of functions in F#

```
let composedFunction = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes >> Array.length
"test" |> composedFunction
```

Type inference correctly defines the type of composed function `string -> int`. But compiler cannot pick correct overload of `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` method:

> Error FS0041: A unique overload for method 'GetBytes' could not be
>   determined based on type information prior to this program point. A
>   type annotation may be needed. Candidates:
>
> System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(chars: char []) : byte [],
>
> System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(s: string) : byte []Blockquote

Is there any way to *compose* correct overload of `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` which accepts string parameter?

Or course, I can do following

```
// declare function which calls correct overload and then use it for compostion
let getBytes (s: string) = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes s      
let composedFunction = getBytes >> Array.length

// start composition with ugly lambda
let composedFunction =
  (fun (s: string) -> s) >> System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes >> Array.length
```

But I wonder if there is any way without additional function declarations to make the compiler pick right overload according to the inferred `string -> int` type of composed function?

Comment: Did you try specifying the type on the function, like `let composedFunction : string -> _ = ...`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always add annotations:

```
let composedFunction : string -> _ = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes >> Array.length
```

or

```
let composedFunction = (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes : string -> _) >> Array.length
```

Answer (score 4):

As your example shows, .NET methods do not always compose well - I think the idiomatic approach in such situations is just to use the .NET style when you're dealing with .NET libraries (and use functional style when you're dealing with functional libraries).

In your specific case, I would just define a normal function with type annotation and get the length using the `Length` member rather than using the function:

```
let composedFunction (s:string) = 
  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s).Length
```

The existing answer shows how to get the composition to work with type annotations. Another trick you can do (which I would definitely *not* use in practice) is that you can add identity function on `string` to the composition to constrain the types:

```
let composedFunction = id<string> >> System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes >> Array.length
```

It's fun that this works, but as I said, I would never actually use this, because a normal function as defined above is much easier to understand.